# Changing email addresses on my @me.com and @icloud.com

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, accounts

When I was married I started both my @me.com and @icloud.com accounts.  The accounts are my first name and last (previously married) name run together.  Now that I am divorced I don't want that as my email.  I would rather have a different name at the front of my email.  How do I go about changing both accounts to another name and getting all my devices and itunes accounts moved over.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, as was stated, you cannot change your @me.com or @icloud.com email addresses independently of your Apple ID. What I would recommend doing is setting up a Gmail (or other) address and using that as your primary Apple ID email (as well as all your normal email for that matter).

If you have a Mac you can even move all the email from your @icloud.com/@me.com account to your new Gmail account simply by setting up both and dragging the folders from one mail account to the other.

After you set up a Gmail email address you can edit your Apple ID [preferences at this site](https://appleid.apple.com). That way, all you ever basically see is the new Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, depending on your situation, you may not be able to change your email address. You can check [this Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5621?viewlocale=en_US) out for details.

If you sign up for an entirely new account, you'd lose the purchases you made under your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Go into icloud mail and select preferences in settings on the left sidebar at the bottom. Select "Accounts" which will list your @me.com and @icloud.com aliases.  The @me.com cannot be changed, but you can create a new alias of the email address you would prefer.  This address will be an @icloud.com address.

Then go to "composing" tab.  Set default address to the new alias you created.  Then below that, deselect all the other email accounts and select the new alias.

This doesn't get rid of the @me.com email, but when sending mail, it will at least use your preferred address sending and receiving.  Occaisionally the @me.com will pop up, but for the most part you can just forget about that address and use your new icloud alias.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do here would be to change your Apple ID name, which is used to form your @me.com and @icloud.com email addresses.

I haven't done this myself before, but Apple's [HT5622](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5622) document includes the following, which seems to explain how this can be done:

[image]

However... I don't completely understand this (eg exactly what they mean by "Apple ID Name").  So perhaps the best approach is to contact Apple Support and ask them.  Their page for Apple ID Support is [here](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/).

Comment: PS @heather If you do contact Apple, perhaps you could record their advice here, to help other people in the future... you could write your own answer, or add a comment... Good luck!