# How to change @icloud.com email

Tags: icloud

For some reason, I discovered I have an old iCloud email that is associated with my account. However, the section of the email before the domain (XXXX@icloud.com) is based on a retired AOL email that I haven't used in about 10 years. How do I either delete this email from my account (unsure what this is associated with as a side note, my Apple ID?) or change this email if I am forced to keep it?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92038/173522